# How to export multiple Release or Builds from Azure DevOps Pipeline to desktop?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to export all the Azure DevOps Release or Builds to desktop? There is a way to export each one through the Azure DevOps UI website and it saves as a json file.

I guess we can use this RestAPI for release found on the Microsoft Website but how do we export all the Azure DevOps Release or Builds to desktop using the same name that that it has on the Azure DevOps UI website?

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=6.0
```

Which RestAPI do we use for build? There is build and build definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to get all build and release definitions. If this is the case, you should refer to the following apis:

[Gets a list of definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=6.0

With optional parameters:

GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?name={name}&repositoryId={repositoryId}&repositoryType={repositoryType}&queryOrder={queryOrder}&$top={$top}&continuationToken={continuationToken}&minMetricsTime={minMetricsTime}&definitionIds={definitionIds}&path={path}&builtAfter={builtAfter}&notBuiltAfter={notBuiltAfter}&includeAllProperties={includeAllProperties}&includeLatestBuilds={includeLatestBuilds}&taskIdFilter={taskIdFilter}&processType={processType}&yamlFilename={yamlFilename}&api-version=6.0
```

[Get a list of release definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0

With optional parameters:

GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?searchText={searchText}&$expand={$expand}&artifactType={artifactType}&artifactSourceId={artifactSourceId}&$top={$top}&continuationToken={continuationToken}&queryOrder={queryOrder}&path={path}&isExactNameMatch={isExactNameMatch}&tagFilter={tagFilter}&propertyFilters={propertyFilters}&definitionIdFilter={definitionIdFilter}&isDeleted={isDeleted}&searchTextContainsFolderName={searchTextContainsFolderName}&api-version=6.0
```

Comment: Thankyou. How can I export all of them to desktop instead of doing one at a time using the same name that that it has on the build or release page?

Comment: The apis above gets a list of definitions, not one definition.